# Dynamically adding the endpoints in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm

I have an application which has two layers of service code in Spring. UI sends request to controller-A and controller-A sends request to multiple microservices in Spring boot. This is implemented in this way to do some basic validation before sending the request to the actual microservices and for some security purpose. Now since the application is growing, I am facing one issue that for every new end point, I need to add that to my controller-A application so that UI can use it. I want to reduce this effort and want to store the end point in Database or some static configuration.

Is there any way to do it in Spring boot so that a single controller method can take all the requests and divert it to the correct microservice based on some static configuration?

Comment: idk about adding routes dynamically (shuld be totally possible on route matching level) but you can always have wildcard route like @GetMapping(/myApi/*) and do the routing yourself for incoming requests.

Comment: Have you considered Spring Cloud Gateway as a solution? Its main purpose is routing to multiple microservices and your validation logic can be implemented in the form of filters.

Comment: @birca123 No I need to read about it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you can think of some of the gateways in this? You can write your own or use the spring cloud gateway.